# How to find minimum$(|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+\cdots+|a_0|)$ if $f(x)=0$ has at least one root $x\in (0,r)$?

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0,a_i\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N.$

How to find minimum$(|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+\cdots+|a_0|)$ if $f(x)=0$ has at least one root $x\in (0,r)$?
(For example, $r=10^{-10}$)

How about if we need all the roots of $f(x)=0$ are real numbers? Thanks in advance!